# TSQL 'create assembly' not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlclr

I've added a simple reference to my SQL Server 2008 CLR project (hosted in VS2012).

If I compile naively, it throws this:

> SQL06503: Assembly 'microsoft.sharepoint, version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=71e9bce111e9429c.' was not found in the SQL catalog.

If I enable "Model Aware" and "Generate Sql Script" on the reference, it seems to want to pull in the entire assembly *inline, in hexadecimal format* to an SQL script, which (a) seems crazy and (b) predictably hits the SQL script size cap and fails.

If I try writing this in a script:

```
create assembly [microsoft.sharepoint, version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=71e9bce111e9429c.]
    from N'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll'
    with permission_set = safe
```

then I get this (un-Googleable) error:

> SQL70502: The assembly source is not valid. Only binary literals are allowed.

which also seems crazy, considering that the official documentation from Microsoft at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189524(v=sql.105).aspx explicitly shows that I should be able to add a `<client_assembly_specifier>` string.

How do I add this reference?

Comment: do you actually have a reference to ''microsoft.sharepoint' ?

Comment: Yes. It's a regular CLR reference in the project.

Comment: That `.` (dot) after the `publickeytoken` value seems out of place to me.

Comment: It does to me too, but removing the dot does not change the error.